# If I changed oracle tnsnames.ora , shall I restart the DB or listeners or just leave it?

Tags: oracle

If I changed oracle tnsnames.ora , shall I restart the DB or listeners or just leave it ?

Answer (score 6):

It depends on what changed. If an alias used by a database link changed, it could be useful to close old session that have that link open. Otherwise, no restarts are needed on the rdbms server side.

Answer (score 2):

There is no need to restart anything. The listener doesn't use tnsnames.ora, only clients attempting to connect through the listener do.

Answer (score 1):

No need to restart anything on the server end (listener or DB).  The client reads the tnsnames.ora and tries to access server described by the connect string in the file.